# pH value of a very dilute alkaline solution

Tags: acid-base, ph

What is the pH of a $\pu{10^-9 M}$ $\pu{NaOH}$ solution? I think it is 5.

Comment: Do you know what is the pH of _pure water_?

Comment: It's PH7, why do you ask?

Comment: Good. So it was 7, and then you added some alkali. You can't expect water to become more _acidic_ as a result, can you?

Comment: No. You are right. Is it then 9?

Comment: How so?$\mathstrut$

Comment: pH= 7.002 maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Something has the concentration of 10^-9 molar. What? The concentration of added OH-.

If added [OH-] = 10^-9, then the original concentration of OH- (10^-7 at 25 C) will increase, to a first approximation, to 1.01 x 10^-7 M. Then the [H+] concentration will decrease to 0.99 x 10^-7. The log of 0.99 x 10^-7 is -7.004365 and the negative of that is 7.004365 and that's the pH.

Solving the quadratic equation  would show that, in a second approximation, the pH is even closer to 7.00 (thanks to Oscar Lanzi).

Considering that the dissociation constant of water changes much more than this over a small range from 20 C (pH=7.08) to 30 C (pH=6.92), it suggests that adding that small an amount of NaOH makes a negligible change in the pH. It does require attention to how big numbers in the exponent can have tiny effects, tho.

Comment: $[\ce{H^+}]=0.995×10^{-7}$.

Comment: I thought this: pH= 14-pOH ; pOH=-log(c0(NaOH)). 14-9=5. where is the fault?

Comment: You have the hydroxide from the base and also hydroxide ions from the autionization.  The latter is affected by adding the base, but if you work that out and add it in you get more than $10^{-7}$ M total hydroxide ions and there is no paradox.  However,  the answer's claim of $1.01×10^{-7}$ is not correct either.  It should be $1.005×10^{-7}$ with hydrogen ions reduced to $0.995×10^{-7}$.  The difference between hydroxide and huydrogen ions and the added base $=10^{-9}$, and the product has to be (in this problem) still $10^{-14}$.